# Symfony & easyadmin : how to deal with dependent entities?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, easyadmin

I use easyadmin with an entity "Client" which has a field linked to another entity "Country".
I managed to make the admin form, by adding to the Country entity a __toString() function, to avoid the error

> "Object of class App\Entity\Country could not be converted to string"

.

Now when I try to save th entry, i get the error :

> Expected value of type "App\Entity\Country" for association field
>   "App\Entity\Client#$country

Some help please !

Edit :

App\Entity\Client :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;
use Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Traits\SoftDeleteableEntity;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ClientRepository")
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable()
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"companyname", "firstname", "lastname", "email"}, message="There is already an account with this username")
 */
class Client
{
    use TimestampableEntity;
    use SoftDeleteableEntity;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $companyname;

    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Country")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $country;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\State")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $stateprov;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getCompanyname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->companyname;
    }

    public function setCompanyname(string $companyname): self
    {
        $this->companyname = $companyname;

        return $this;
    }

    ...

    public function getCountry(): ?string
    {
        return $this->country;
    }

    public function setCountry(string $country): self
    {
        $this->country = $country;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStateprov(): ?state
    {
        return $this->stateprov;
    }

    public function setStateprov(?state $stateprov): self
    {
        $this->stateprov = $stateprov;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

App\Entity\Country

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;
use Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Traits\SoftDeleteableEntity;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CountryRepository")
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable()
 */
class Country
{
    use TimestampableEntity;
    use SoftDeleteableEntity;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=3, nullable=true)
     */
    private $iso3;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=2, nullable=true)
     */
    private $iso2;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $phonecode;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $capital;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $currency;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint")
     */
    private $flag;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\State", mappedBy="country")
     */
    private $states;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->states = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIso3(): ?string
    {
        return $this->iso3;
    }

    public function setIso3(?string $iso3): self
    {
        $this->iso3 = $iso3;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIso2(): ?string
    {
        return $this->iso2;
    }

    public function setIso2(?string $iso2): self
    {
        $this->iso2 = $iso2;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPhonecode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->phonecode;
    }

    public function setPhonecode(?string $phonecode): self
    {
        $this->phonecode = $phonecode;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCapital(): ?string
    {
        return $this->capital;
    }

    public function setCapital(?string $capital): self
    {
        $this->capital = $capital;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCurrency(): ?string
    {
        return $this->currency;
    }

    public function setCurrency(?string $currency): self
    {
        $this->currency = $currency;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFlag(): ?int
    {
        return $this->flag;
    }

    public function setFlag(int $flag): self
    {
        $this->flag = $flag;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|State[]
     */
    public function getStates(): Collection
    {
        return $this->states;
    }

    public function addState(State $state): self
    {
        if (!$this->states->contains($state)) {
            $this->states[] = $state;
            $state->setCountryId($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeState(State $state): self
    {
        if ($this->states->contains($state)) {
            $this->states->removeElement($state);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($state->getCountryId() === $this) {
                $state->setCountryId(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }


public function __toString(){
    // to show the name of the Category in the select
    return $this->name;
    // to show the id of the Category in the select
    // return $this->id;
}
}
```

App\Entity\State

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;
use Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Traits\SoftDeleteableEntity;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\StateRepository")
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable()
 */
class State
{
    use TimestampableEntity;
    use SoftDeleteableEntity;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint")
     */
    private $flag;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\country", inversedBy="states")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $country;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFlag(): ?int
    {
        return $this->flag;
    }

    public function setFlag(int $flag): self
    {
        $this->flag = $flag;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCountry(): ?country
    {
        return $this->country;
    }

    public function setCountry(?country $country): self
    {
        $this->country = $country;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString(){
        // to show the name of the Category in the select
        return $this->name;
        // to show the id of the Category in the select
        // return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your `Entities` both?

Comment: please see edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove `?string` from the class `Client`. because getCountry is returns `Country` class.

`class Client {
.......................
    public function getCountry():
    {
        return $this->country;
    }`